# install bluetooth in samsung R430, windows 7

Tags: drivers, laptop

how can i install the bluetooth driver in this laptop in windows 7. The installation process tells me that i need to activate the bluetooth device to continue, but how can i activate if till that moment the device doesn't exist. There isn't any button or switch to activate the device manually.

Edited:
it's the np-r430 model. I read somewhere (a users forum, not official info) that for Chile and Argentina this models doesn't have built in the bluetooth device, but the US models have it. Maybe for some political and weird reason they send to south american laptops without that. The link of my notebook's specifications in an AR domain:
[np-r40](http://www.samsung.com/ar/consumer/monitor-peripherals-printer/notebook/notebook/NP-R430-JA04AR/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail)

Comment: You might edit your post to include the Make and Model of your PC, not all PCs have bluetooth capability.

Comment: My Spanish is horrible, but it does look to me like the laptop does have bluetooth. Also, I feel for you! In my country, we too often get computers without any extras. Could you boot some GNU/Linux Live CD and get outputs of lspci and lsusb? They may help.

Comment: Did you try experimenting with Fn+F7? Maybe3 it does something. Also, try with the button which controls wireless network. It may do something too. Check the manual one more time too.

Comment: @AndrejaKo yes i try. At the beginning those buttons doesn't work, but after install of Easy Display Manager all buttons do something except Fn+F7. I'm thinking seriously that device isn't present. The bad thing was that the seller tells me that it has bluetooth, apparently based only in the chart but without any real experimentation that effectively prove that. I'm going to call to Samsung Chile to get a definitive answer

Answer (score 1):

If there is no button or switch, try checking the BIOS. It is possible that bluetooth can be enabled or disabled in the BIOS.

Comment: Also make sure that you do in fact have bluetooth capability! Just because the series may support it, it does not mean that your particular laptop has bluetooth installed.